# В своей кнопке запускать процедуру на OnClick если кнопка недоступна

Tags: delphi, классы, события

Создал свою кнопку:

```
Type
  TMyButton = class(TButton)
    private
      AMode:Boolean;
    public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent; AMode:Boolean);
  end;

constructor TMyButton.Create(AOwner: TComponent;AMode:Boolean);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
end;
```

Кнопка создается динамически с разными названиями и в разных местах на форме, но в некоторые передается параметр AMode=False, а в другие AMode=True;

Хочу сделать, чтобы если в AMode передали True при нажатии на выключенный TMyButton.Enabled=False срабатывал OnClick с сообщением ShowMessage('Компонент выключен'), а если AMode=False то не срабатывало событие OnClick (как по умолчанию). Это для любой вновь созданной TMyButton.

Никак не могу понять как это осуществить.

Насколько я знаю, OnClick не работает для выключенной кнопки и даже если создать свою процедуру, то он не сработает.

Comment: А зачем создавать подобный геморрой? Не проще ли обратиться к событиям напрямую?

Comment: @ViktorTomilov Пытался. да вот не пойму как.

Comment: Поясните (можно просто на словах, а не кодом), какое событие от какого компонента/в какой компонент или фунцию вы хотите передать, и вам ответят, а пока вопрос очень сумбурный и непонятный.

Answer (score 1):

Я правильно понимаю, что вам нужно отловить событие клика мышкой на кнопке, свойство Enabled которой установлено в FALSE?
Если это действительно так, а не попытка как-то странно воспользоваться событиями, то вам следует обращаться не к обработчикам события кнопки Button1 (она запрещена), а к обработчикам событий её родителя (пусть это будет Form1). В итоге, если кнопка разрешена, то отрабатывает процедура MyButtonClick, если запрещена - работает FormMouseDown:

```
type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
      Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;


  TMyButton = class(TButton)
    private
      FMode:Boolean;
    public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent; AMode:Boolean);
  end;


var
  Form2: TForm2;
  btn1:TMyButton;


procedure MyButtonClick;
begin
   // действия, если кнопка разрешена
end;


constructor TMyButton.Create(AOwner: TComponent;AMode:Boolean);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  @OnClick:= @MyButtonClick; // можно идти через TNotifyEvent, но так тоже можно :)
  FMode:=AMode;
  Enabled:=AMode;
end;


procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);

begin
   btn1:=TMyButton.Create(Self,true); // или FALSE, как пожелаете
   btn1.Parent:=Form2;
end;

procedure TForm2.FormMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
var
  l,t:Integer;
begin
   if Button = mbLeft then
     begin
       l:=btn1.Left;
       t:=btn1.top;
       if (X>=l) and (X<=btn1.Width+l) and (Y>=t) and (Y<=btn1.Height+t) then
          begin
            // действия, если кнопка запрещена
          end;     
     end;
end;
```

Comment: Это будет работать только для существующих кнопок, которые выключены, а при создании новой кнопки, мы не знаем какая она и где, а параметр AMode имеет значение. Это касается динамически создаваемых кнопок.

Comment: @SovereignSun Это почему же? Если вы размещаете кнопку на родителе, то вы знаете где она - вы всегда можете получить её значения Top, Left, Heigth, Width относительно родителя. Специально проверил код для "динамической" кнопки - всё работает :)

Comment: @SovereignSun Если же вы разместили кнопку с Enabled:=true, там автоматически должен сработать перехват события нажатия на неёё, которое вы должны определить уже в классе TMyButton

Comment: @SovereignSun ну, вот вам код, который отлавливает событие в любом случае на ДИНАМИЧЕСКИ создаваемой кнопке. Смотрите обновлённый ответ.